# How do I configure my multithreaded .NET 5 application to use all Windows CPU groups?

Tags: multithreading, .net-core, f#, .net-5, cpu-usage

I'm trying to migrate a project from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET 5, but the performance of my program has dropped significantly. Parts of the program exploit parallelism for bulk operations on a server with 96 Cores and 192 Logical processors split across 4 CPU groups.

I'm running the program on a Windows Server 2016 with the .NET 5 Runtime installed (.NET 5 SDK not installed). The project is written in F# 5.0.

In .NET Framework 4.7.2 we used the following `app.config`-file which successfully made the program run across all 192 Logical processors, achieving ~98% CPU utilization:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <Thread_UseAllCpuGroups enabled="true" />
        <GCCpuGroup enabled="true" />
        <gcServer enabled="true" />
        <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

After migrating to .NET 5 (and by extension .NET Core) the CPU utilization dropped, and I am having trouble increasing it again.

According to [Microsoft's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/) `app.config` is not used to configure .NET Core projects, replaced by `[appname].runtimeconfig.json`. To accommodate this change i have added a `runtimeconfig.template.json` to my project:

```json
{
  "configProperties": {
    "System.GC.CpuGroup": true,
    "System.GC.Server": true,
    "COMPlus_gcAllowVeryLargeObjects": 1
  }
}
```

This produces the following `[appname].runtimeconfig.json`-file:

```json
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.CpuGroup": true,
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "COMPlus_gcAllowVeryLargeObjects": 1
    }
  }
}
```

The property `System.GC.CpuGroup` seems to work, giving me a peak of ~28% CPU utilization by distributing threads across a single CPU Group:

[image: Screenshot of Windows Task Manager showing 100% utilization of 48 of 192 logical processors for an overall utilization of 28%]

Now I need to distribute threads across different CPU Groups.

`Thread_UseAllCpuGroups` was omitted due to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/threading#cpu-groups) saying the variable is N/A in `runtimeconfig.json`, and must be set as an **environment variable**.

According to [Trying to use Thread_UseAllCpuGroups in a .Net Core app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573561/trying-to-use-thread-useallcpugroups-in-a-net-core-app) this only works when set at the command line, but i have tried multiple ways of setting it:

1. CommandLine using `set COMPlus_Thread_UseAllCpuGroups=1` before running my program.
2. Setting the variable though `Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Environment Variables`.
3. Defining a `launchSetting.json`-file with the variable and copying it to the output directory.
4. Manually setting the variable in my `program.fs`-file using `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("COMPlus_Thread_UseAllCpuGroups", "1")`.

None of the above methods have worked, and I am unsure what I am doing wrong, especially given how few posts I can find online on this issue.

Finally my question is: How do I make my .NET 5 console application utilize all my logical processors?

*Edit: I've tried lifting the project to .NET 6 and F# 6, but the problem still remains.*

Comment: I see that documentation page and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector#cpu-groups) say to use environment variables prefixed with `COMPlus_` for .NET <6, but does using `DOTNET_Thread_UseAllCpuGroups` make any difference?

Comment: Related: [Does .NET support NUMA core processing?](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58184)

Comment: Is there any sensible reason you can't upgrade to .NET 6 and F# 6? Have you even bothered to try it just to see if it makes a difference? There's been a lot of optimizations there.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews the documentation also states that the `COMPlus_` prefix should still work, but `DOTNET_Thread_UseAllCpuGroups` did not change anything.

@BentTranberg i have tried upgrading, but the issue still persists. Only 1 CPU group is being utilized...

Answer (score 1):

@Hobitten: Although I would prefer the old `Thread_UseAllCpuGroups` , I created a starter batch file (which I find really stupid!!!). Maybe this helps. The reason why I use the difference cases is only because I didn't (and still don't) know if the enevironment vars a case sensitive.

```
set complus_GCCpuGroup=1
set COMPlus_GCCpuGroup=1
set COMPlus_Thread_UseAllCpuGroups=1

set DOTNET_GCCpuGroup=1
set DOTNET_Thread_UseAllCpuGroups=1

call <yourexe>
```